# Create a custom dashboard using Jira's REST API, with Temporal View of data

Tags: rest, jira, jql

I am looking to create a custom dashboard in which I would display:
Number of Open Issues Per Project with TYPE="508"
With the Time axis division as "daily" or "weekly"
Number of Closed Issues Per Project with TYPE="508"
With same X-Axis

Here is a JQL to start with, but this JQL does not get continuously progressive data:

`project = ZZZZ AND (summary ~508 or labels = 508) and created >= -4w and type != epic`

Is Jira API the only way to do it? If yes, then how would I create the Front end, should I use React, or VueJS or this can be done from Confluence using JQL? or REST API.

So the question also is:
Where would this data be stored?
Does the Jira API able to get ALL data ( is a first class citizen )?
JQL VS REST API, which one to use in this case.

The Graph I am looking to build is somewhat like:
[image: Example Graph showing trend over time]